# How to access parent PHP class properties in extended classes

Tags: php, class, oop, object

I tried accessing parent class properties in its daughter class  but I keep getting this error  ***Fatal error: undefined class constant 'arms' on line 26 of blabla.php.*** 
This is my code below in blabla.php

**blabla.php**

```
<?php
class mother
{
  public $legs;
  public $arms;
  public $eyes;


   function say($arm,$eye,$leg)
  {
   $this->arms =  'pretty';
   $this->eyes = 'stunning';
   $this->legs = 'beautiful slim';
  }
  }


class daughter extends mother
{
 public $newArms;
 public $newEyes;
 public $newLegs;

 public function newSay()
 {
   $this->newArms = parent::arms;
   $this->newEyes = parent::eyes;
   $this->newLegs = parent::legsparent::arms;
   echo 'I have a beautiful daughter who has '.$this->newArms.' arms, '.$this->newEyes.' eyes and '.$this->newLegs.' legs';
 }

}


$baby = new daughter();
$baby->newSay();


?>
```

if there is a mistake in my code, please show me and how to correct it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are making a fundamental mistake. Daughter should not extend Mother. A mother has a daughter, the daughter is a new entity, not an extension of the mother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got your syntax wrong.

```
ClassName::NAME
```

is used to access class constants as your errormessage says.

A class constant is defined using the `const` keyword in the class' body.

However, you want to access the property of an object. You have to use `$this` for that

Inside a methods body: `$this->propertyName`. You have to make sure that the property is visible to its child classes, so you either need to make it protected or public or have the magic `__get` method implemented or have custom getters and setters defined and call them instead of the actual property.

You also don't  use the `parent` keyword for this. `parent` always looks for static fields of the parent class and is generally not tied to an instance. (You can however use it to call a method from the parent class in the context of its child class)

Comment: Seems that way. Corrected now. Just wanted to show what the syntax he used is actually meant for.

Comment: Thanks again. I got you, so that means I can only access those properties through functions, the __get() and the __set().

Comment: I got it worked just that its a bit more coding than i planned expecially when trying to access many **mother properties**  Thanks a lot.